# cache manger : redis get value undefine

Tags: node.js, redis, nestjs

```
i am trying to get value from redis cache . use nest.js/ node .js 

i am using cache manger . nestjs typescript 

    

@Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cacheStore: CacheStore


        const cacheData = await this.cacheStore.get<Number>(id);

            if (!isNil(cacheData)) {

                const data=await plainToClass(Number, cacheData, { exposeUnsetFields: false });
                return  childrenCount = { childrenCount: data };
            }
            if (isNil(cacheData)) {


                const response = await this.service.findChildrenCountById(id);
                const resolved =await plainToClass(Number, response);
                const tk=await this.cacheStore.set(id, resolved, { ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 }); //  save for 24 hours
                console.log('tk===', tk);
             childrenCount = await { childrenCount:  tk };
          return await childrenCount;
            }
```

i try also with .then but not got result..........

i have problem with this line of code

const cacheData = await this.cacheStore.get(id);

Comment: cacheData is undefine

Comment: Where are you importing `CacheStore` from the class is `Cache` from [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching#interacting-with-the-cache-store)

Comment: it is working . but problem with promise . i got value with promise .   const cacheData = await this.getValue(id).then(data => {
    console.log('from this line ======================', data);
   });

Comment: how can i convert  above then to await

Comment: Dont use `.then()` if you want to use await, else return the value from the callback function in `then()`